# JMeter crashing on Mac with brew

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I am having an issue when open JMeter, it doesn't open, but rather crashes and gives the error below.

```bash
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007ff80599cb73, pid=45712, tid=259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (21.0.2) (build 21.0.2)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AppKit+0xc8fb73]  _NSCarbonMenuCrashIfNeeded+0x258
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/j/hs_err_pid45712.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.3/libexec/bin/jmeter: line 199: 45712 Abort trap: 6           "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" $ARGS $JVM_ARGS $JMETER_OPTS -jar "$PRGDIR/ApacheJMeter.jar" "$@"
```

I have search for solutions online, uninstall and install again, restart my computer, but the same thing keeps happening. Please help

Comment: Is there any useful log in the file /Users/temitopekayode/hs_err_pid45712.log ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're facing [Homebrew issue 150824](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/150824) and discussion states that this is a bug on Apple's part.

Try upgrading your MacOS to 14.2 or higher, JMeter from homebrew works fine on 14.3.1 at least.

Also be aware that you can always [install the desired JDK and JMeter manually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) without any so-called package managers. For JDK the easiest way is using [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) and JMeter can be just downloaded from [official website](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) or from [archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) if you want a previous version for any reason, download, unpack and you're good to go.